# How can I add a volume for the App_Data folder using docker-compose.override.yml?

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I am experimenting with Visual Studio's `docker` support and want to add a volume mount for `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data`.

My `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.1-windowsservercore-1709
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

My `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

version: '3.4'

```
services:
  my.app:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}myapp
    build:
      context: .\My.App
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Now I've tried just about every variation of specifying `volumes` in my `docker-compose.override.yml` file, including:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  my.app:
    volumes:
      - "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\App_Data"
    ports:
      - "80"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat

services:
  my.app:
    volumes:
      - "C:\\temp\\dockerappdata1":"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\App_Data"
    ports:
      - "80"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat

services:
  my.app:
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: "app_data"
        target: "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\App_Data"
    ports:
      - "80"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
volumes:
  app_data:
```

But in all cases, I cannot run the project and it reports either some kind of configuration issue with `compose` or else an issue when starting the container, with the super-unhelpful message:

```
encountered an error during Start: failure in a Windows system call: The compute system exited unexpectedly.
```

What is the right syntax?

Comment: Narrow down to actual issues, that is don't have any overrides files, remove any services from compose files, remove ports, networks etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  my.app:
    volumes:
      - "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\App_Data"
    ports:
      - "80"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat

services:
  my.app:
    volumes:
      - "C:\\temp\\dockerappdata1":"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\App_Data"
    ports:
      - "80"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat

services:
  my.app:
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: "app_data"
        target: "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\App_Data"
    ports:
      - "80"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
volumes:
  app_data:
```

The problem I think here is, you are trying to mount a directory which is already there.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you'd like to volume mount "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data" into the container, correct?

If that's the case, here's what you should add in the yaml file:

```
services:
  my.app:
    volumes:
      - C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\App_Data:C:\\temp\\dockerappdata1
     # Syntax is HOST_PATH:CONTAINER_PATH:[ro/rw] (the access mode is optional)
    ports:
      - "80"
```

More info on the syntax: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3